# Page Animation Using the Same Page

Tags: smartface.io

I have a simple question. I'm trying to use animation on a single page such as Page1. For example if I change the Label text and press a TextButton, I would like it to transition leftToRight.  When I try to use the Pages.Page1.show(3,4,0,false,false), the updated label is shown with no transition effect.  I've tried to go between 2 different pages and it does transition properly.  Is there a way to do this with 1 page since I want to keep the same page elements but just update the text content and display the updated page with a transition effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can not run page animation for the same page. But you can try something like that. 
Just run animate method only for the updated object. For example;

```
var myLabel = new SMF.UI.Label({
    top : "25%",
    left : "15%",
    height : "10%",
    width : "70%",
    text : "hello"
});
var myButton = new SMF.UI.TextButton({
    top : "50%",
    left : "15%",
    height : "10%",
    width : "70%",
    text : "myButton",
    onPressed : function () {
        myLabel.alpha = 0;
        myLabel.text = "world";
        myLabel.animate({
            property : "alpha",
            endValue : 100,
            motionEase : SMF.UI.MotionEase.plain,
            duration : 3000,
            onFinish : function () {
                //do your action after finishing the animation
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Add these two objects(myLabel, myButton) to your page. 
When pressed to button, label's text changes, it becomes invisible with `alpha = 0`, and then it becomes visible again with animate method.